# Login With Google in React Native and NodeJS Backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

How to login with Google in React Native for frontend and NodeJS MonggoDB for backend?

Comment: By implementing the relevant libraries according to the documentation. If you have a specific implementation question, feel free to ask that. Here's some reading material to get you started: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/authenticate-users

Comment: The user will need to already have a Google account and use his Google email and password. You just need to open a Google Developer account and use the OAuth2.0 key and paste a code snippet supplied by Google that displays the Login with Google button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this "react-native-google-signin" Library on frontend side.

This is the usage

```
import {GoogleSignin, statusCodes} from 'react-native-google-signin';
 useEffect(() => {
configureGoogleSign();
}, []);

function configureGoogleSign() {
GoogleSignin.configure({
  webClientId: WEB_CLIENT_ID,
  offlineAccess: false,
});
}
const signIn = async () => {
try {
  await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
  const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
  setgmail(userInfo);
 
  //Navigate user where you want and store information
} catch (error) {
  if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
    // user cancelled the login flow
  } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
    // operation (f.e. sign in) is in progress already
  } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
    // play services not available or outdated
  } else {
    // some other error happened
  }
}
};
```

For Backend, you need to verify the user access token that will send by frontend.

```
await axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=' + access_token,
            withCredentials: true
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log('response==>', response.data);
                flag = true;
                id = response.data.kid
            })
            .catch(function (response) {
                console.log('error');
            });
```

Comment: Why i sholud verify user access token? What if i just select email sent from frontend and do checking email in database (backend)?

Comment: You need to just verify the token that is correct or not.

Comment: Thank you sir for your help

Answer (score 0):

Improving upon @[Awais Ibrar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69071387/9571770)

Instead of sending Access Token, send Authorization Code from frontend in the Request Header and in the backend use Authorization Code to get Access Token.

Note - Attackers can easily insert Access Token, since source of Access Token cannot be easily verified. 
Source : [Google Developer Documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/migration-guide)

Step 1 : Get credentials(OAuth 2.0 Client IDs) from GMAIL API from Google Cloud Console.

Step 2 : In React Native

```
import { GoogleSignin, statusCodes } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';

function configureGSignin() {
  GoogleSignin.configure({
    androidClientId: 'ANDROID_CLIENT from Google Cloud Console',
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'],     // find more scopes here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#gmail
    webClientId: `WebClientId from Google Cloud Console`,
    offlineAccess: true, // if you want to process data on backend
    iosClientId: `IOS_CLIENT_ID from Google Cloud Console`,
  });
}
const signIn = async () => {
    try {
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      //save details of userInfo in the frontend and request backend using userinfo.serverAuthCode
     
      //Navigate user where you want and store information
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
        // user cancelled the login flow
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
        // operation (f.e. sign in) is in progress already
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
        // play services not available or outdated
      } else {
        // some other error happened
      }
    }
    };
function backendRequest() {
const url = 'YOUR_BACKEND_URL';
const serverAuthCode = the_same_code_you_get_in_userinfo
axios.post(url,{body data},{ headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${serverAuthCode}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    },
  )
  .then(function (response) {
    //on successful request
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    //on error
  })
  .finally(function () {
    // always executed
  });
}
```

Step 2 in Backend

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
try {
const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
  getAccessToken(token);

res.status(200).send("OK");
} catch (error) {
res.status(401).send("Unauthorized");
}});

async function getAccessToken(code) {
  try {
    const { tokens } = await oAuth2Client.getToken(code);
    logger.info("Tokens : ", tokens);
    saveCredentials(tokens);
  } catch (err) {
    logger.info("Error :", err);
  }
}
```

Comment: await getAccessToken(token)